# Android file scan

Tags: java, android

I have a music player application. I need to scan  all music files which are in phone but Android 5.0 and later versions i can't access SD-card

permissions in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

before 5.0 version this part works

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ist=new ArrayList<>(new getplaylist().getPlayList("/"));
```

this part return only phones storage not sdcard

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ist=new ArrayList<>(new
        getplaylist().getPlayList(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
       .getPath()));
```

playlist method

```
 public class getplaylist {
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getPlayList(String rootPath) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        File rootFolder = new File(rootPath);
        File[] files = rootFolder.listFiles(); 
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                if (getPlayList(file.getAbsolutePath()) != null) {
                    fileList.addAll(getPlayList(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<>();
                song.put("file_path", file.getAbsolutePath());
                song.put("file_name", file.getName());
                fileList.add(song);
            }
        }
        return fileList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Do not do this. Query the `MediaStore` for all audio files. Also, there are no `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` or `READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Like [official android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalMediaDirs()) says for API level 21 and above:

> **getExternalMediaDirs**
>
> Returns absolute paths to application-specific directories on all
>   shared/external storage devices where the application can place media
>   files. These files are scanned and made available to other apps
>   through MediaStore.

use `getExternalMediaDirs` instead of `getExternalStorageDirectory` in:

```
 getplaylist().getPlayList(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()));
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all check external storage available or not with the device. After that these are the following method which can access external memory Directory-

1. getExternalStorageDirectory();
2. getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type);
3. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
   must include permission into manifest file.

   ```
   String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath();
   ```

   or
   File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);